# XML Restriction number between range with exceptions

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Let's say I've something like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AYE">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
            <xs:minInclusive value="32768"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="65535"/>
                    <!-- Or, for instances, 5, 15, 20 or 245 -->
        </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

Is it possible to define a simpleType which restricts a number between a range [a,b] but also allows some pre-defined numbers which are less than a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
    <xs:simpleType name="exceptions">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
            <xs:enumeration value="5" />
            <xs:enumeration value="15" />
            <xs:enumeration value="20" />
            <xs:enumeration value="245" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="range">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
            <xs:minInclusive value="32768"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="65535"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="AYE">
        <xs:union memberTypes="range exceptions" />
     </xs:simpleType>
```